# How to identify if a column value is decreasing over a period of time in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I want to identify the stocks which have decreased in value in the past ten days.
For example, in the data shown below, the stock has decreased in value in the past ten days.

I want to highlight these kind of stocks.
I would like to know how to write a query for this.

I am using MySQL 8+.
Any help is most appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Regards
Vadi

```
ID   SECURITY   MARKET_PRICE     EFFECTIVE_DATE
1    stockname  10.0000000000    2021-01-01
2    stockname  9.0000000000     2021-01-02
3    stockname  8.0000000000     2021-01-03
4    stockname  7.0000000000     2021-01-04
5    stockname  6.0000000000     2021-01-05
6    stockname  5.0000000000     2021-01-06
7    stockname  4.0000000000     2021-01-07
8    stockname  3.0000000000     2021-01-08
9    stockname  2.0000000000     2021-01-09
10   stockname  1.0000000000     2021-01-10
```

Comment: Compare the current price with the price 10 days ago and if the earlier one is higher, then it is decreasing.

Comment: you may try to take reference value of stock before ten days and select stokes which are less than that value.

Comment: Hi Shadow/Lalit, Thanks a lot for your quick reply. Perhaps, I should have been more clearer with my question. I want to know if the stock has been continuously decreasing over the past ten days. Thanks again. Vadi

Comment: First you have to define what "decreased in value" actually is. Are you looking for a trend or just simply "a lower value than 10 days ago". Today -0.01 lower than 10 days ago could be a decrease, but the stock could be on the way up from 5 days ago.

Comment: Hi Sam020. Thanks for your reply. Your point is taken. I am looking for stocks which have continuously decreased in value in the past ten days as shown in the sample data. Thanks.

Comment: Make it 3 days instead of 10, and see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: And, as a hint, try finding stocks which have increased in value (compared with a previous day) within the last 3 days. Your desired result set is all stocks NOT in that list.

Answer (score 1):

For your apparent need, something like the following would suffice...

```sql
WITH 
cte1 AS ( SELECT *, LAG(price) OVER (PARTITION BY market 
                                     ORDER BY date) <= price AS not_decreased
          FROM table ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT *, SUM(decreased) OVER (PARTITION BY market 
                                         ORDER BY date 
                                         RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 10 DAY PRECEDING 
                                                   AND CURRENT ROW) AS not_decreased10days
          FROM cte1 )
SELECT * 
FROM cte2 
WHERE not_decreased10days = 0
```

Comment: Hi Mr Akina. Thanks a lot for your quick reply. I had to make some corrections to your query as shown below. It is working correctly. But I still need to test it with proper data. Thanks a lot.

Comment: WITH cte1 AS (SELECT *, LAG(market_price) OVER (PARTITION BY security ORDER BY effective_date) <= market_price AS decreased
          FROM market_price_test),
cte2 AS (SELECT *, SUM(decreased) OVER (PARTITION BY security ORDER BY effective_date desc 
                                         RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 10 DAY PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS not_decreased10days
          FROM cte1)
SELECT * FROM cte2 WHERE not_decreased10days = 0 order by effective_date;

Comment: @Vadi Yes, I have tried to post the self-explaining pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I have also come across the below query. This also seems to work correctly, if anyone is interested.

```sql
SELECT  MPTEST.*         
            ,IF(@M_PRICE >= MARKET_PRICE, 'True', 'False') As IS_VALID
            ,(@M_PRICE:=MARKET_PRICE) as M_PRICE
        FROM (    
        SELECT * FROM market_price_test WHERE EFFECTIVE_DATE <= '2021-01-10'
ORDER BY EFFECTIVE_DATE DESC LIMIT 10
) MPTEST,(SELECT @M_PRICE:= 
                    (SELECT MARKET_PRICE FROM market_price_test WHERE EFFECTIVE_DATE <= '2021-01-10'
                    ORDER BY EFFECTIVE_DATE DESC LIMIT 1)
) MPTEST1
ORDER BY SECURITY, EFFECTIVE_DATE;
```

Comment: `ORDER BY EFFECTIVE_DATE DESC LIMIT 10` may be problematic if some day is absent in the data - you'll test more wide dates range in such case.